# No CiviCRM pages on completely new install

Tags: installation

- New Server: Intel Xeon-E2388G 3.2, with 64GB RAM and 2 1TB nvme on
  soft raid running ubuntu server
- Database Server: 10.4.24-MariaDB-1:10.4.24+maria~focal
- PHP 7.4.30, Memory Limit 512MB
- Drupal 9.4.5, Standard Install
- CiviCRM 5.52.2 Separate database with all permissions on Drupal and CiviCRM DBs and SUPER
- en_GB localisation files installed after cli installation
- No warnings at all on Drupal Status Report

Installed clean installation on the above, composer Drupal, composer CiviCRM as per CLI installer guide. Visiting the /civicrm page for the first time, seen permissions problem but fixed this on /sites/default/files/civicrm/...
Refreshed with the problem text gone. Nothing displaying, other than the civicrm footer. No CiviCRM pages at all.

Followed the troubleshooting steps - caches, menu etc.
Log file contains the following:

```
Aug 19 03:12:28  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

[code] => -18
[message] => DB Error: no such table
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`name` AS `name`, `a`.`label` AS `label`, 

`a`.`description` AS `description`, `a`.`entity_name` AS `entity_name`, `a`.`items` AS `items`
FROM  a
ORDER BY `label` ASC
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civicrmdb.a' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`name` AS `name`, `a`.`label` AS `label`, `a`.`description` AS `description`, `a`.`entity_name` AS `entity_name`, `a`.`items` AS `items`
FROM  a
ORDER BY `label` ASC
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civicrmdb.a' doesn't exist].....
```

Any ideas? Stuck! Thanks in advance.

Edit after further research:
CLI install command used:

```
cv core:install --cms-base-url="https://example.com" --lang="en_GB" --db="mysql://civicrmuser:password@localhost:3306/civicrmdb" -v
```

Result of cv:

```
{
    "srcPath": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core",
    "setupPath": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/setup",
    "settingsPath": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/web/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php",
    "templateCompilePath": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c",
    "cms": "Drupal8",
    "cmsBaseUrl": "https://example.com",
    "db": {
        "server": "localhost:3306",
        "username": "civicrmuser",
        "password": "password",
        "database": "civicrmdb",
        "ssl_params": []
    },
    "cmsDb": {
        "server": "localhost:3306",
        "username": "drupaluser",
        "password": "password",
        "database": "drupaldb",
        "ssl_params": null
    },
    "siteKey": "mySiteKey",
    "credKeys": [
        "aes-cbc:hkdf-sha256:myCreds"
    ],
    "signKeys": [
        "jwt-hs256:hkdf-sha256:mySign"
    ],
    "loadGenerated": null,
    "lang": "en_GB",
    "components": [
        "CiviEvent",
        "CiviContribute",
        "CiviMember",
        "CiviMail",
        "CiviReport"
    ],
    "extensions": [
        "org.civicrm.search_kit"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "civicrm.files": {
            "url": "https://example.com/sites/default/files/civicrm",
            "path": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/web/sites/default/files/civicrm"
        }
    },
    "settings": [],
    "mandatorySettings": [],
    "extras": []
}
```

Output from cv vars:show -

```
{
    "CIVI_CORE": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/",
    "CIVI_DB_ARGS": "-h localhost -u civicrmdb -pcivicrmdb -P 3306 civicrmdb",
    "CIVI_DB_DSN": "mysql://civicrmuser:pass@localhost:3306/civicrmdb?new_link=true",
    "CIVI_DB_HOST": "localhost",
    "CIVI_DB_NAME": "civicrmdb",
    "CIVI_DB_PASS": "password",
    "CIVI_DB_PORT": 3306,
    "CIVI_DB_USER": "civicrmuser",
    "CIVI_FILES": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/",
    "CIVI_LOG": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.random.log",
    "CIVI_SETTINGS": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/web/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php",
    "CIVI_SITE_KEY": "mySiteKey",
    "CIVI_TEMPLATEC": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/",
    "CIVI_UF": "Drupal8",
    "CIVI_URL": "https://example.com/libraries/civicrm/core/",
    "CIVI_VERSION": "5.52.2",
    "CMS_DB_ARGS": "-h localhost -u drupaluser -pdrupaldb -P 3306 drupaldb",
    "CMS_DB_DSN": "mysql://drupaluser:password@localhost:3306/drupaldb?new_link=true",
    "CMS_DB_HOST": "localhost",
    "CMS_DB_NAME": "drupaldb",
    "CMS_DB_PASS": "password",
    "CMS_DB_PORT": 3306,
    "CMS_DB_USER": "drupaluser",
    "CMS_ROOT": "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/web/",
    "CMS_URL": "https://example.com/",
    "CMS_VERSION": "9.4.5",
    "IS_INSTALLED": "1",
    "SITE_TYPE": "cv-auto"
}
```

Contents of vendor/civicrm... appears complete. Contents of web/libraries/civicrm... is definitely incomplete with hundreds of files missing including jquery etc which is obviously why it's no working.

Is the full core and packages required at /libraries/ or should CIVI_URL in cv be something else?

Comment: I followed all the installation instructions exactly. I am now trying to figure out why civicrm is looking in web/libraries for dependencies and not in vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages?! I have installed the asset plugin. Or do I need to modify paths away from the default?

Answer (score 0):

Did something fail during one of the composer commands at one point? You may need to run `composer civicrm:publish` manually then to copy files into web/libraries. For the DB Error, that error has come up before but shouldn't on a brand new install. Usually `cv ext:upgrade` will fix that.